# Can't install driver for D-link DWA 131e1

Tags: debian, wifi

I bought a wifi adapter which is D-link DWA 131E1 for my debian device. I cant find a driver to install it working. Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `rtl8192eu` driver:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo make
sudo make install
echo -e "8192eu\n\nloop" | sudo tee /etc/modules
echo "options 8192eu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/8192eu.conf
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
sudo update-grub; sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot
```

To install the driver through DKMS see [Building and installing using DKMS](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver#building-and-installing-using-dkms).